Node.js library that just loads DOM and scripts but can handle async
I am trying to load a page to scrape that loads the data I need only after multiple recursive async script loads. But due to the count of pages and items, can't use things like Puppeteer or Selenium.
I tried jsdom as it seemed perfect, having cookie jars, a DOM and script execution. But seems to run into an issue with the nested XHR as
dom = new JSDOM(``, {
  url: "https://www.pnp.co.za/c/pnpbase?currentPage=" + p_ind.toString(),
  contentType: "text/html",
  referrer: "https://pnp.co.za/",
  includeNodeLocations: true,
  resources: "usable",
  storageQuota: 10000000,
  pretendToBeVisual: true,
});

causes querySelectorAll('div[class~="product-action"]') to not find any results.
Any help?

The product-action items are not in the RAW HTML of the page so you must use tools that actually load the page and run the Javascript in the page because that is apparently how those items get added to the page.  Puppeteer is likely your best choice so you need to solve whatever issues you have when using it.  JSDOM will only get you what it's the actual HTML.  You can see the raw HTML with View/Source in Chrome.

i got that from inspect element on chrome, my logic was that jsdom should suffice, since the async js adds the data to dynamically made dom elements

I'd suggest you read the doc page here and specifically the runScripts option.  JSDOM is not a full browser implementation.  It apparently can run some scripts, but not all scripts within the page, but does not do so by default.

As others have pointed out, using jsdom may not be the best approach here, since this library does not implement a full headless browser.
Still, if you want to load a page with jsdom, you should use the fromURL method. As you expect the page to execute its scripts, you will also need to add the runScripts: "dangerously" in the options provided to the method.
Also, as jsdom does not support some browser APIs such as IntersectionObserver (which is used in the URL you want to scrap) we can silence the errors jsdom throws to the console by creating a virtualConsole which mutes the errors.
Putting all this together, you could scrape the page with something in the lines:
// Define and setup virtual console to mute jsdom errors.
const virtualConsole = new jsdom.VirtualConsole();
virtualConsole.on('error', () => {});

const url = 'https://www.pnp.co.za/c/pnpbase?currentPage=' + p_ind.toString();
JSDOM.fromURL(url, {
    referrer: 'https://pnp.co.za/',
    includeNodeLocations: true,
    resources: 'usable',
    storageQuota: 10000000,
    pretendToBeVisual: true,

    // Tell jsdom to execute the page scripts (take into account
    // that this can be dangerous)
    runScripts: 'dangerously',

    // Use the virtual console
    virtualConsole
}).then(dom => {
    const { window } = dom;

    // Now the page is loaded, you should wait for the contents you
    // expect to scrap to be loaded. For simplicity let's use a 
    // setTimeout that will wait 20 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
        const actions = window.document.querySelectorAll('a[class~="product-action"]');

        }, 20000);
    });

